# Selecting records in SQL Server

Tags: select, sql-server-2012

I have table with two columns with this sample data:

```
Column1         Column2
------------------------
A                B
A                C
A                D
R                B 
R                D
S                E
```

If I pass the input value of Column2='B', it will display these records:

```
Column1         Column2
-------------------------
A                B
A                C
A                D
R                B 
R                D
```

because Column2 'D' Contains 'A' in column1 and 'R' in Column1. So it fetches
all the records which contains 'A' and 'R'

Suppose if I pass an input if Column2='C', it will display these records

```
Column1         Column2
-------------------------
A                B
A                C
A                D
```

because Column2 'C' Contains 'A' in Column1. So it fetches all the records which contain 'A'.

Original table contains > 100k records. So we will give any input for column2.

Comment: Unable to understand!

Comment: Sorry..if u give condition in select statement  where column2='D' .i wrongly mentioned Column2='B'.it display  the records which column1 contains 'A' and 'R'.Because Column2= 'D' Contains 'A' in column1 and 'R' in Column1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting Records based on column value in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291064/selecting-records-based-on-column-value-in-sql-server)