# Selecting Records based on column value in SQL Server

Tags: select, sql-server-2012

I have table contains two columns having below input records.

Sample Input Records

```
Column1         Column2
-----------------------
A                B
A                C
A                D
R                B 
R                D
S                E
```

in the above records if i give where condition Column2='D'  it will display below output records.

Output Records

```
Column1         Column2
-----------------------
A                B
A                C
A                D
R                B 
R                D
```

Logic:In the Sample input records Column2='D' contains two records.These two records contain the colum1 values as 'A' and 'R'.so i want to  display the records which contains 'A' and 'R' from the input records

Suppose if give where condition Column2='C' i it will display below output records.

Output Records

```
Column1         Column2
-----------------------
A                B
A                C
A                D
```

Logic: in the sample input records Column2='C' contains one record. This record contains the column1 value of 'A'. So I want to display the records which contain 'A' from the input records

Comment: Ram.. you can edit your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289488/selecting-records-in-sql-server with correct explaination.. Thanks, TamilPugal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
        Column1 CHAR(1) ,
        Column2 CHAR(2)
    );


INSERT INTO #temp ( Column1 ,
                    Column2 )
VALUES ( 'A', 'B' ) ,
       ( 'A', 'C' ) ,
       ( 'A', 'D' ) ,
       ( 'R', 'B' ) ,
       ( 'R', 'D' ) ,
       ( 'S', 'E' );

SELECT *
FROM   #temp
WHERE  Column1 IN (   SELECT Column1
                      FROM   #temp
                      WHERE  Column2 = 'D' );


DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Result:

```
+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+
| A       | B       |
| A       | C       |
| A       | D       |
| R       | B       |
| R       | D       |
+---------+---------+
```